# Getting rid of testing errors in react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, npm

I am getting the following testing errors:

```
    console.warn
      err!

      at node_modules/react-query/lib/core/mutation.js:115:32
      at tryCallOne (node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)
      at node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:123:15
      at flush (node_modules/asap/raw.js:50:29)
```

My tests are passing just fine but I need to get rid of these errors and I am unsure on how to do that?

I did add the following line to jestSetup.js file:
`jest.spyOn(console, 'warn').mockReturnValue();`

This does get rid of the errors but I would like a more permanent solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the test/s that are actually throwing those warnings, and the spy just for those:

```
test('pass with warnings', () => {
  let spyWarn = jest.spyOn(console, 'warn').mockImplementation(() => {});

  // your logic
  spyWarn.mockClear();
});
```

Or if they are a bunch, playing with `beforeAll`, `beforeEach` and `afterAll`